# SoapClient->MyAction($params), Formatting the $params array

Tags: php, soap

I'm using PHP SoapClient() to consume a web service.

```
$sc = new SoapClient($uri);
$sc->MyAction($params);
```

$params would be an array to create the XML below, but I'm unsure how to format the array where there are multiple OrderLine keys.

```
<args>
  <OrderLines>
    <OrderLine>
      <LineNumber>1</LineNumber>
      <Product>Acme Foos</Product>
      <Description>Bars and Bazzes</Description>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Price>5.00</Price>
    </OrderLine>
    <OrderLine>
      <LineNumber>2</LineNumber>
      <Product>Kittens</Product>
      <Description>Very sleepy</Description>
      <Quantity>1</Quantity>
      <Price>12.00</Price>
    </OrderLine>
  </OrderLines>
</args>
```

This is a dump of the array format I'm sending in, unsuccessfully because I'm not sure how to make the array with multiple **OrderLine** keys.

```
[args] => Array
(
    [OrderLines] => Array
      (
        [0] => Array
          (
            [LineNumber] => 1
            [Product] => 'Acme Foos'
            [Description] => 'Bars and Bazzes'
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Price] => 5.00
          )
        [1] => Array
          (
            [LineNumber] => 2
            [Product] => 'Kittens'
            [Description] => 'Very sleepy'
            [Quantity] => 1
            [Price] => 12.00
          )
      )
)
```

When sending this to the web service, I am getting the following SoapFault exception:

> Server was unable to read request. ---> There is an error in XML
>   document (2, 1001). ---> Input string was not in a correct format.

Comment: I can understand that you are unsure. However, if you outline what you did so far (and how it worked out), it would be easier to answer your question.

Comment: Ok, I updated with the details of what I'm submitting, and the SoapFault exception faultstring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This example is correct.  The error was not related to the array.  It was some other invalid data in my params.